# What is a good approach to constructing a modular parser both for REPL interpreters and compilers?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter

What is a good approach to build a versatile parser both for REPL interpreters and compilers? What I mean by the interpreters is kind of a read-eval-print loop. 
To support both of them, the parser should support a whole program parsing and a line-by-line parsing. The LALR(1) algorithm introduced by the Dragon book is good for a whole program parsing, but it should be engineered a little bit for being used to support a line-by-line parsing simultaneously. Since the two styles of the parsing share the same grammar for the programming language, I believe that there would be a modular method for building a single parser for the two purposes, but I can't find it. Can you help me on this matter?

Comment: LALR parsing is not at all engineered for line-by-line parsing. You should design a parser that builds a syntax tree, and then write either a compile backend that processes it or an interpreter that interprets it, or both. The syntax tree itself is the interface to both: not the parser.

Comment: Can the source code change while you're running the interpreter? If not, why not use an AST for both, as @EJP recommends?

Comment: Yes, I assume that users can write an arbitrary new statement that the interpreter will take and will evaluate.So, The abstract syntax trees in the interpreter will change dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a [GLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) parser (or GLL), and you to abuse it particular way.

What makes the GLR parser useful here is its willingness to pursue *all* possible parses until one resolves out as the valid answer.  (Most of the standard parsers offered (LL, LALR, recursive descent) pursue only a single possible parse and often cannot handle complexities introduced by long (e.g, indefinite) lookaheads.

With this in place, you now adjust your original grammar having a goal rule G and set of other nonterminals A-Z:

```
 G -> A;
 A -> B;
 B -> C;
 ...
 Y -> Z;
```

to be:

```
 G -> A;
 G -> B;
 G -> C;
 ...
 G -> Z
 A -> B
 B -> C
  ...
```

that is, you add *every* nonterminal as an additional goal rule.

Now your parser will any valid nonterminal of the langauge.
You can use "nonterminal reduces to G" as a trigger to decide
if you want to "compile" the nonterminal if the original toplevel
nonterminal A is returned, or "interpret" that nonterminal (if it is not the
original top level nonterminal, e.g, B-Z) or just ignore that input and wait for more if you think interpreting things like then clauses without the if part are not interesting.

You can explicitly modify the grammar (easist) or you can bend the GLR parser
to launch all nonterminals in its starting state, whcih has the same effect.

My company uses GLR to parse source code patterns (as nonterminals) rather than  "compile" or "interpret", but that uses exactly the same trick.

It isn't easy to modify a GLR parser to do it, but it isn't "technically" hard, either.   You do have to deeply know how parsers,and esp. GLR work, to work out the details and tie it all together.